# How to benchmark bashrc / zshrc and prompt rendering time?

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, zsh, bashrc

As im currently experimenting with new stuff in my prompt i need a way to tell what the performance impact is.

How can i monitor how long it takes to render my prompt and the time it takes to source the .*rc?

Comment: Why on Earth do you have a prompt that takes so long to render that you are concerned about how long it takes?! The configuration files only get sourced when the shell is started.

Comment: rendering cvs information, ssh-agent status, user rights ... takes a while - i need to find a compromise between information and performance. on my *nix system execution is generally pretty fast but i use my prompt under cygwin aswell and there it can easily take a few seconds to render the prompt. That's why i need to benchmark certain parts of my prompt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With these command you should be able to benchmark the startup times, including sourcing of rc files (+ one print invocation, which shouldn't add to much overhead):

```
time zsh -i -c "print -n"
time bash -i -c "echo -n"
```

With more than 1000 lines in my `.zshrc` this takes 0.3 sec on my cygwin installation. And no, it's really no high-end-machine (iCore2Duo P8700).

Regarding the prompt rendering time:

- in `bash` it's possible to `time` builtin commands. However, I don't know a possibility to render `$PS1` as a prompt.
- in `zsh` it's the other way round, with `print -P $PS1 $RPS1` you can render you prompt with a print command. (man zshbuiltins: "**[print] -P**     Perform prompt expansion"). But it seems time doesn't work with builtin commands. That's why I hacked together this one:

  ```
  cumul=0; for i ({0..99}) {
    start=$(date +%s.%N)
    end=$(date +%s.%N)
    (( cumul+= (end-start) ))
  }
  overhead=$((cumul/100.))
  cumul=0; for i ({0..99}) {
    start=$(date +%s.%N)
    print -P $PS1 $RPS1
    end=$(date +%s.%N)
    (( cumul+= (end-start) ))
  }
  print $((cumul/100. - overhead))
  ```

  First, this measures the overhead which is caused by the `date` commands. It is done a 100 times for better statistics.
  Then the `print -P $PS1 $RPS1` is included, also executes a 100 times, and the overhead determined in the first part is subtracted. Consecutively invocations shows that you cannot trust the 1ms digit, but the 10ms digit seems reliable. With a expected value in the order of seconds that should suffice.

But, as @Michael Kjörling already mentioned in a comment, the prompt should render in no time. So either, you should think about how to optimize your prompt or take into account, that in my experience the *prompt rendering time* (as in your question) is only a tiny part of the *prompt display time*. (I speak here mainly about the Z shell, but I assume in bash there are similar concepts.) Because there are other functions that get executed before the prompt is displayed. This is what comes immediately to my mind:

- `precmd`: Executed  before  each  prompt; use `which precmd` to see what it is in your case
- if you have the option `sharedhistory` enabled, the file `~/.zsh_history` (or whatever you named it) get's read. Especially if your home directory is on a remote filesystem, significant delay can be induced. I also observe once in a while several seconds before the prompt is displayed when the NFS server is heavily loaded.

A tool to analyze the time requirements of external programs / internal functions in detail is the `zsh/zprof` module, loaded by

```
zmodload zsh/zprof
```

From `man zshmodules`: "When  loaded, the zsh/zprof causes shell functions to be profiled.  The profiling results can be obtained with the zprof builtin
       command made available by this module."

Comment: `real    0m11.332s` cries in MSYS